# openpyxl: How to set a chart series Title to a cell reference instead of a string value?

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl

I'm trying to use a cell reference for my chart-series title. I can get the text from the cell but cannot create a reference to it.

I've tried the following:

```
pxl.chart.Series( ... title='=LiveData!$B$1' )

ref = pxl.chart.Reference( sheet, min_col=1,  min_row=1 )
pxl.chart.Series( ... title=ref )
```

When opening Excel, I was hoping for series title: =Sheet1!$B$1  - a live cell reference.
Instead the latter solution gives me =''Sheet'!$B$1'

Comment: What is the result when you use the pxl.chart.Reference object?

Comment: pxl.chart.Reference( sheet, min_col=1,  min_row=1 )  produces   =''Sheet'!$B$1'

Comment: Deleted my comment about $A$1 getting appended. setting max_col=min_col cleared up that issue but still getting a string instead of a Ref ="'LiveData'!$E$1"

Comment: Still no joy. Just tried  chart.Reference( range_string='Sheet1!$E$1' ) and still got a string result    ="'Sheet1'!$E$1"
Also tried Reference( range_string='Sheet1!D1' ). Curiously it still produced a string but re-included the $ signs.  ="'Sheet1'!$D$1"

Comment: Did you try the answer I posted below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic I found [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/chart/series_factory.py)

```py
from openpyxl.chart.series import Series, SeriesLabel, StrRef

series = Series(...) # don't give it a title

series.title = SeriesLabel(strRef=StrRef("LiveData!$B$1"))
```

Comment: Thx, that worked! For whatever it took me down a completely different class path and I had to rejig my whole series definitions. All for the better, mind you. Seems much more consistent now.